# Swift delegate call

Tags: swift, delegates, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch

What is best practice:

```
if let delegate = delegate {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        delegate.action(self)
    }
}
```

or

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    delegate?.action(self)
}
```

I have been preferring the first one, since it looks like it avoids switching context, but I am not sure if this is the case. or is there something better?

Thanks.